# 18.10 booting black screen and white underscore freeze

Tags: boot, 18.10

When I boot up all I see is black screen with white underscore blinking. This is not fresh install since i have been using it for over 2months with no problems. I use 3 monitors if that may cause any problems. Sometimes before when booting up i would have to disconect 3rd monitor and reconnect it after bootup so that 3 monitor would work.
What I have tried:
In recovery mode dpkg. No errors popped up.
With bootable usb tried to check ubuntu install files, no corruptions or errors.
I can access terminal via recovery->root or by recovery->network changing file system state to read/writte and then on reboot alt + f2 and loging in to root terminal. 
Btw on recovery menu filesystem state is read-only. If that may cause problems.
What else could I do to fix this, don't want to reinstall yet because of many configurations for programming which would take whole day to setup after reinstall.